# Laravel 5 barryvdh/laravel-dompdf time exceeded

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5

I'm using DOMPDF in my project and I making some tests before I implement in my system but very time I ran the service it show me that 60 seconds time exceeded,
First I created a controller:

```
 public function invoice() 
    {
        $data = $this->getData();
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $invoice = "2222";
        $view =  \View::make('pdf.invoice', compact('data', 'date', 'invoice'))->render();
        $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        $pdf->loadHTML($view);
        return $pdf->stream('invoice');
    }

    public function getData() 
    {
        $data =  [
            'quantity'      => '1' ,
            'description'   => 'some ramdom text',
            'price'   => '500',
            'total'     => '500'
        ];
        return $data;
    }
```

then I add the route :

```
Route::get('pdf', 'PdfController@invoice');
```

The last part I add is a folder in view with the name pdf and the file invoice.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Example 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')}}">
  </head>
  <body>

    <main>
      <div id="details" class="clearfix">
        <div id="invoice">
          <h1>INVOICE {{ $invoice }}</h1>
          <div class="date">Date of Invoice: {{ $date }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="no">#</th>
            <th class="desc">DESCRIPTION</th>
            <th class="unit">UNIT PRICE</th>
            <th class="total">TOTAL</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="no">{{ $data['quantity'] }}</td>
            <td class="desc">{{ $data['description'] }}</td>
            <td class="unit">{{ $data['price'] }}</td>
            <td class="total">{{ $data['total'] }} </td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td >TOTAL</td>
            <td>$6,500.00</td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
  </body>
  <script src="{{asset('plugins/jquery/js/jquery-2.1.4.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="{{asset('plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js')}}" ></script>
</html>
```

URL: `http://localhost:8000/pdf`

I really appreciate if some one can tell me where is my mistake.

Comment: Are you sure you're setting laravel-dompdf correctly? Why don't you just use `PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);` like suggested in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

Your script executed for more then 60 seconds and was terminated and not related to Laravel but php. The default limit is 60 seconds, stored in php.ini file. To temporarily extend the time limit, you may use following line if code in your current script, but try to optimize your script too (if possible)

```
set_time_limit(120); //120 seconds = 2 minute
```

[Read more on php manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

> You can do set_time_limit(0); so that the script will run forever -
>   however this is not recommended and your web server might catch you
>   out with an imposed HTTP timeout (usually around 5 minutes). You may
>   also use

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 120);
```

[Check ini_set.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

**Update**

It might be a namespace problem. Try this

```
$pdf = PDF::loadHTML('your view here ');
    return $pdf->stream();
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the real problem, I believe instead that the script is taking too much time to execute the task on just a single array.

Comment: yes, it is taking too much time that's why you need to increase max_execution_time of the script .

Comment: I'm checking the file php.ini and i found this, max_execution_time = 120.

Comment: apparently the problem is not the execution time, i ran it acouple times and still the same

Comment: I told you. This is a consequence, not the cause.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Bootstrap framework, it will be really slow. Just delete it and use native css.

Comment: That might add to the performance issues, but that is hardly an overall solution